# Changing the "henkan" Kanji autocomplete highlight colour

Tags: ios, uitextfield, cjk

When typing with the Japanese keyboard, Kanji are suggested with a special highlight around the typed Kana.

[image: example highlight]

Is it possible to change the colour of this highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
textField.markedTextStyle = @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}
```